# Possible to copy a circuit from 1 Logisim .circ file into another Logisim .circ file?

Tags: digital-logic, design, 7segmentdisplay, logic-gates

I'm using Logisim to experiment with Electrical Circuit design, and I was wondering if it is possible to copy a circuit created in 1 Logisim **.circ** file and place it into a different Logisim **.circ** file or instance? I'd really like to reuse some components I've previously put together into a new file for a larger design, but can't seem to find a way to get the circuit from one file/instance to another.

It is possible to copy a circuit within a file and paste into another circuit in that same file, but I can't find anywhere online or in Logisim documentation about getting a circuit from 1 file into another.

Anyone know if this is possible? I'd really prefer not to repeat all the work over if I don't have to...

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked this a while ago, but in case you still need the answer, yes it is possible. According to http://www.cburch.com/logisim/docs/2.1.0/guide/menu/edit.html

"Note: Logisim's clipboard is maintained separately from the clipboard for the overall system; as a result, cut/copy/paste will not work across different applications, even including other running copies of Logisim. If, however, you have multiple projects open under the same Logisim process, then you should be able to cut/copy/paste between them."

Answer (score 1):

in the target project session, Project > Load Library > Logisim Library. Then locate to your source project. Then source project will be added to target project as a library. after that you can copy from it.